# An urn contains 12 red marbles and 10 blue marbles.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We draw five marbles from this urn without replacement. Given that the first two marbles are blue, what is the probability that there is at least one blue marble among the next three marbles?

I'm working this problem like this:
let A = probability first two are blue
P(A) = (10/22)(9/21) = 0.19481
P(A') = 1 -P(A) = 0.80519
let B = probability that at least one of the next 3 is blue.
P(B) = 1 - P(B')
I'm stuck on how to set it up
Any ideas would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the probability that *none* of the remaining three marbles is blue?:

$$P\left(\overline B|A\right)=\frac{P\left(\overline B\cap A\right)}{P(A)}=\frac{\frac{10}{22}\frac{9}{21}\frac{12}{20}\frac{11}{19}\frac{10}{18}}{\frac{10}{22}\frac{9}{21}}$$

and now...end the argument

Comment: I think P(B) = 1 - P(B') + P(A). it the answer would be: P(A) + P(B), does it looks correct at all?

Comment: Hmmm...no. Perhaps we got into notation confusion, but you know what the probability of **the complement** of an event is, right? Observe that above we got this complement of what *you* are interested in...

Comment: Lets see, if I compute P(A) from the original approach I get (10/22)*(9/21). Then I computed P(B) = 1-P(B'). After that I did P (B|A) which is basically what you have in your original post. And here is where I'm stuck at

Comment: @Joz Your $\;B\;$ is pretty messy to be computed: at least one means exactly one **or** exactly two **or** exactly three. We pass to the complement and thus the probability you want is one minus what we did above. Observe that the other answer gives *exactly* the same result...

Comment: Got cha, thank you so much

Comment: @Joz Please do observe that all three answers (so far) give exactly the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You are effectively starting with 12 reds and 8 blues.
The required probability is $$1-p(\text {three reds})=1-\frac {12}{20}\times\frac {11}{19}\times\frac {10}{18}=\frac {46}{57}$$

Comment: yours is simpler, same result, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

P(3rd is Blue, 4th is Red, 5 is Red) $= \frac{8}{20}.\frac{12}{19}.\frac{11}{18}$

P(3rd is Red, 4th is Blue, 5 is Red) $= \frac{12}{20}.\frac{8}{19}.\frac{11}{18}$

P(3rd is Red, 4th is Red,  5 is Blue) $= \frac{12}{20}.\frac{11}{19}.\frac{8}{18}$

P(3rd is Blue, 4th is Blue, 5 is Red)$= \frac{8}{20}.\frac{7}{19}.\frac{12}{18}$

P(3rd is Blue, 4th is Red, 5 is Blue) $= \frac{8}{20}.\frac{12}{19}.\frac{7}{18}$

P(3rd is Red, 4th is Blue, 5 is Blue) $= \frac{12}{20}.\frac{8}{19}.\frac{7}{18}$

P(3rd is Blue, 4th is Blue, 5 is Blue)$= \frac{8}{20}.\frac{7}{19}.\frac{6}{18}$

The required probability $= \frac{5520}{6840}$